# Shortcuts to Partitions not found

Tags: mount, nautilus, partitioning, shortcuts, automount

I have a HDD with 3 partitions: OS, Data_1 and Data_2.

In Nautilus, Data_1 and Data_2 show above "Other Locations" (assuming these are just shortcuts), but unless I actually go into "Other Locations" and select the partition, the "shortcuts" to these do not work (says "not found").

The partitions are set to auto-mount.

Comment: I edited your question and added "How can I find them?" I assume that is your actual problem. Please, what have you done so far to counteract the issue?

Comment: It seems the partitions are not getting auto-mounted at all. "Shortcuts" (bookmarks) not working (saying "not found") is the default behaviour when the partition is not mounted. Did you set the auto-mount option correctly?

Comment: I suspected there was an issue with auto mounting, and I did follow steps outlined in various how to pages ... so I cannot verify that this has in fact been done correctly, I am a complete novice